# Symfony $form->isValid() return false on ajax calls

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, symfony

I have a contact form which I render with the FormTypes and a validation.yml for it. The submitted form is sent via POST and AJAX to a controller action. The problem is that `$form->isValid()` always returns false although I enter correct data into the form. If I delete the validation.yml it still return false. So where does the validation of the form get its data from? Why does it always return false?

Here is the action controller:

```
public function contactAction()
{
    $true = new Response(json_encode(true), 200);
    $false = new Response(json_encode(false), 500);

    $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), new Contact());
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if($request->isMethod('POST') && $request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $form->bind($request);

        if($form->isValid()){
            // email here
            error_log('email worked');
            return $true;
        }
    }
    error_log('email not worked');
    return $false;
}
```

The validation.yml:

```
Namespace\XYBundle\Entity\Contact:
properties:
    name:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 2
            max: 20
    email:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Email: ~
    message:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 10
            max: 10000
```

And here the jQuery/JS code for the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "contact",
            data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
            error: function() {
                $('.error').remove();
                $('#sendError').slideDown('slow');
                $('button').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('button').css("color", "#333333");
            },
            success: function () {
                $('.error').remove();
                $('#success').slideDown('slow');
                $("input[name='contact[name]']").val('');
                $("input[name='contact[email]']").val('');
                $("textarea[name='contact[message]']").val('');
                $('button').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('button').css("color", "#333333");
            }
        });
```

Comment: if you are sending a json back you can use the JsonResponse response instead http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/JsonResponse.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are passing in the data manually, you are forgetting to pass in the CSRF token field `(_token)` which is causing it to always be invalid.

I would suggest doing 
`data:  $('#myForm').serialize()` to make sure all fields are being sent

Answer (score 3):

Don't construct the form data on your self. Primary the CRSF token is missing. JQuery has a good form serializer.

```js
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "contact",
        data: $('#yourFormId').serialize(),
        // ...
    });
```

Btw. two other tipps. Returning an error with HTTP Status Code 403 Bad Request would fit better in this scenario. JQuerys error function should be called with everything != 200.

And for logging monolog is a good thing.

```php
$this->get('logger')->error('email foo bar');
```

Comment: thx for the further tips. the other guy was faster with his answer, but i upvoted you. can you tell me where i can find the log messages then?

Comment: in the `app/logs` folder of your symfony project are the log files. The used log file depends on your environment.